# Dependency not found in Maven Project

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, jackson-databind

I'm trying to add this dependency in my Maven project but it gives me an error like:

"Dependency not found" even though I added the dependency by searching in Intellij IDEA

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
```

Comment: DId you click the "m" button with a little reload icon below that appears in the top right of the pom file?

Comment: Please, post your `settings.xml` file.

Comment: Does `mvn clean install` from command line complete successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you just need to reload project in order to force IntelliJ to download the dependency. Right mouse click on the `pom.xml` in the Project tree -> Maven -> Reload project. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginner so I didn't know. Thanks for help